# ASP .NET database-first picklist field

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to create database table field which needs to have certain value.
For example field called season can have value:
spring, summer, autumn or winter.

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string season { get; set; }
    public int yearNumber { get; set; }
    public string season {get; set; }?
```

Could anyone help me? I'am aware that this question might be a little noobish but I am a totall newbie in ASP .NET not talking about web development...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table called Season.
Reference this table with Foreign-Key relationship.
This is a one-to-many relationship. Each of your Seasons can have many records in the other table.

In this case you should likely create another table that contains the 4 seasons. Often (but not always) you'll want to create an integer Id for each of those seasons, but you could just use the season's name as the Id (a varchar). You would reference this id as a *Foreign Key*. This is known as a Foreign Key relationship in Relational Databases (RDMS's), and it's used to *Normalize* the database. Normalization is what prevents you from repeating data (among other things) over and over, which can sometimes lead to data corruption It can be a little daunting if you're new to it, but it's a good thing to know.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/08/sql-server-%E2%80%93-2008-creating-primary-key-foreign-key-and-default-constraint/